# How can I ignore system created table when i am getting the list of granted privileges given to user in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, schema, privileges

I am using Oracle 11g. I am successfully extracting DDL of database using userA account who created database tables, SP, Functions etc using getddl() method.

Now here is a case userA has shared / grant some action (ie. select) to userB account. and When I tried to get DDL details using same getDDL method, it is not including that shared tables.

To resolve it I used following.

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS;
```

Statement. Using this I can get list of all shared table with some unknow system tables details.

Now I am looking for the solution which either gives only shared tables or a way using that I can ignore (filter) that tables

FYI: When I am executing the above query it gives  [this](http://neelam.sharma.s3.amazonaws.com/001/2015-12-14%205-22-23%20PM.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINHDRCMKC5GUSNFA&Expires=1459362582&Signature=aKomKc7Wzh0l0LCiZiRsF8flNvc%3D) output.
As expected it returns data related to all tables including system tables and all users created in the database including system generated users.

So can please anyone help me to create a query which will give me data related to privileges granted to all the users created manually and not by system?

Comment: Which user are you logged in to execute the query?

Comment: I have logged in from User_1

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of all privileges given to USER_2 from USER_1, you can use the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.USER_TAB_PRIVS T WHERE T.GRANTOR = 'USER_2';
```